# Read and write string in My.Resources

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, resources

I was thinking of using this:
[image]
How can I save something like:

```
Dim sometext As String = TextBox1.Text
My.Resources.Add.Name("foo")
My.Resources.Add.ValueTo("foo") = sometext
' hope you get what I meant.
```

Basically, I want to use this as a database or something.. for saving buttons' names and locations.. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, My.Resources is read only.

You use My.Resources to add resources (such as images, audio, text and whatever else) to your project, so that when you **compile** it, those resources are embedded into the application. This is done for a few reason but 2 that come to mind are:

1. You can use it to store something that may otherwise change location (e.g. an image)
2. Because it's part of the application users can't delete it / move it, which would otherwise break your application.

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wkcc526%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I thought that there's someway to do that. Guess I'll have no choice to use settings.